# Unable to compile class for JSP: BooksWorker cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a Java EE project that contains three files `delete.jsp`, `index.jsp` and `BooksWorker.java`.

Here I can not run `index.jsp`, even if I place `BooksWorker.class` in WEB-IN/classes.
The error I get :

```
type Exception report
```

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
BooksWorker cannot be resolved
21:   String remark = request.getParameter("remark");
22:   if (author != null && title != null 
23:           && year != null && remark!= null) {
24:      BooksWorker.Insert(author, title, year, remark);
25:   }
26: %>
27:

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the right path? See the import and adjust the path WEB-INF/classes/<packagename>BooksWorker.class

Comment: I have no packagename i set this only WEB-INF/classes/BooksWorker.class

Comment: Also tried to reload the context?

Comment: Alexandre, please what you mean by reload the context ?

Comment: You currently are inside an Application Server like Tomcat or Glassfish, generally when you make changes to your application you need to reload it. In linux tou can do this by using "touch web.xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `BooksWorker` class from [unnamed package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2) to a [named package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1). The JSP compiler is unable to access the classes from [unnamed package].

Comment: @mezgani If you get the correct answer, please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error is due to not importing BooksWorker in the jsp.

```
<%@page import="<package name>.BooksWorker"%>
```

Comment: He said that he places `BooksWorker.class in WEB-IN/classes`. I assume it is a class from an unnamed package. Therefore you can't do an `import`.

Comment: Yes, thew package should be named - it is true. But the error "not resolved" is due to not importing